# Why I receive {"ok":false,"error":"channel_not_found"} when I am setting topic in slack?

Tags: javascript, slack-api

Here is my code for setting topic channel and I receive  `{"ok":false,"error":"channel_not_found"}`
while the channel exists and I tried to use channelId instead of using #channelName . but no difference. And the permissions are set correct.

```
function setTopic1() {
var topic = 'testing'
  var url = 'https://xxxx.slack.com/api/conversations.setTopic'
  var payload = {
    'channel': '#temp-w',
    'token': token,
    'topic': topic,
  };

  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': payload,
  };

  if (topic.length > 250) {
    Logger.log("Topic is too long, API request might fail")
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  Logger.log(response)
}`
```

Comment: Is this for a public or private channel?

Comment: It's a public ,but I want to post it on private as well, but this one I tried on public one.

Comment: @ Erik Kalkoken Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what was the issue. 
First as we integrate bot to channel ,I also needed to invite @channelName.
And in payload it would be correct instead of using #channelName to channelID.
It didn't work for me with channelName, it works with channelName when I posted message in channel but for set channel it works with channelId in payload

Answer (score 7):

Yeah you most likely need to add the bot to the channel. I did this by first going to a channel where I know the bot works already. I clicked on the bot, and clicked on `add this app to a channel...` and clicked on the new channel. Then it should work!

Answer (score 3):

(Just adding my answer in case someone finds it helpful in the future)

Probably, you have not invited the bot to the channel yet. Go to the channel #temp-w, invite the bot to this channel and then try sending the http request.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps someone not to make the same mistake:

I added the bot while installing to a server. But that only adds the integration to the channel, additionally you need to add the bot (invite it) to the channel, it's not there automatically! :)